# Symfony2 render form for each list item

Tags: php, forms, symfony

How could I achieve a form for each list item using csrf and validation in symfony way?

I have a Task entity, which has comments property with a relation OneToMany. So I want to list all tasks and include a hidden comment form for every task. Usually I pass generated forms from controller to template, but how to create them dinamically in template?

```
{% for task in tasks %}
<taskinfo>
<task comment form>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved** using this way:

In **controller**:

```
    $forms = array();
    foreach($tasks as $task) {
        $entity = new TaskComment();
        $forms[$task -> getId()] = $this ->createTaskCommentForm($entity, $task -> getId());
    }
   return $this->render('Bundle:blah:index.html.twig', array(
        ....
        'forms' => $forms
    ));
```

An then comment box near every Task box in **view**:

```
    ...task info...
    {% for task in tasks %}
        <div class="comment-box">
             {{ form(forms[task.id]) }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

P.S. I'm using collapsible panels to show/hide each task.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to embed a collection of forms? If so, [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) and [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) you can read more.

Comment: I am not sure. How can I set and access that form while looping through Tasks?

Comment: @JustinasLelys if your problem is solved, you can post your answer and mark it as right ;)

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a best way to do this. But why not :)

Comment: @JustinasLelys if your solution works fine, why not?) If someone post the better way to do this, you can vote up and mark it as right :)